# Any gems to perform inline FullText searches without a server

Tags: ruby

Let's say I just have a simple array (just inline, not stored anywhere):

```
books = ["Joe Smith's Beginning", "Joe Smith's Revelation", "Get Success"]
```

I'm really keen on using tricks found in fulltext search servers like using double quotes for exact match, or "-" to exclude words.

But I don't want to use any server, I just want to perform such search inline like:

```
books.search("Joe Smith OR Success -beginning")

-> books = ["Joe Smith's Revelation", "Get Success"]
```

Are there any ruby gems that allow such thing?

Comment: SQLite has [full-text searching options](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3) and doesn't require a server.

Comment: have you tried looking at [ruby-toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) ?

Comment: What is the use case? Where will the code run? Can you use SQLite or other libraries? Or does it need to be pure ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MySQL ? If yes, you could use the builtin full text search abilities. You can do it from scratch (should be simple) but there is a gem for that : 
https://github.com/makandra/dusen